# Definig a regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to define a regex in Javascript that allows to verify an other input regex

Any helps ar welcome

thanks.

Comment: Just for clarification: You want a regex that verifies the syntax of another regex?

Comment: Your question is rather vague. What does _"allows to verify an other input regex"_ mean exactly? Could you give some examples?

Comment: Ok... what's the regex you want to verify?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of this, but I think that you can't do this with regex; not in general anyway - you'd need something that's actually Turing-complete IIRC.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler way:

```
try
{
    new RegExp(inputRegex);
}
catch (e)
{
   alert("Invalid regex");
}
```

Comment: I am so thankful for tou help you have really solved my problem thank you

Comment: +1 Ingenious. So simple it never came to my mind - using the tools you have :D